# Fixed ratio column CSS puzzle

Tags: javascript, css

I am struggling to work the css out for this scenario. I have a fixed height header (no problem there). Underneath I have two side by side blocks.

The blocks should go from the header to the footer (with a small margin).

I would like the first block to have a minimum width of 25% of the browser width. The second block should have an aspect ratio of 4:3. It should be able to achieve this in most cases by expanding the first column past 25%.

In the cases when the first block can't shrink below 25% width, the right block should still be 4:3 but vertically centred in the view.

[image]

Is this possible with just CSS? I need to support modern browsers and IE 10.

Thanks

Comment: could you provide a snipet ? that would be relly helpful for us

Comment: what do you mean by ` aspect ratio of 4:3` can you please explain it

Comment: I mean the blue box height should always be 75% of it's width. The yellow column can expand and shrink. This means if the user has their browser quite short the yellow box will shrink. If the browser is taller the yellow box will expand, but the blue box will always have the same aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code below:

```css
header {
  height: 50px;
}
.container {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.left-block {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 25%;
  width: 25vw;
  background: yellow;
}
.left-block,
.right-block {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.right-content {
    background: blue;
    width: 74vw;
    height: calc(75vw * .75);
}
```

```html
<header>
    header
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-block">left content</div>
    <div class="right-block"><div class="right-content">right content</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the `vw`css unit with a `min-width` on the yellow block should do what your wanting. Hard to say for sure with out a fiddle or codepen to look at  your actual code.

```
min-width: 25vw;
width: 25%;
```

For the blue area at a 4:3 ratio you can use the `vw` css unit again for the width and use the [calc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) for the height.

```
width:75vw;
height: calc(75vw * .75);
```